# Exception of 50000 characters at 'SpreadsheetApp.flush()' in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import a list from my Gmail into a spreadsheet.
It has worked flawlessly several times, but I decided to do some cosmetic changes and now I get a baffling error:

```
  var l = artikelen.length; //l = 40 in this case
  var importSh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("import");
  var range = importSh.getRange(2,1,l,1);
  range.setBackground("#ab6e6e"); 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //throws error 'Input exceeds the limit of 50000 characters in a cel'
```

What is that? I'm not trying to put anything in a cell?? I'm just ordering to pick a range and set a colour AFAIK. Which in fact is not executed either...

What am I overlooking here?
Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: It means one of your cells has  more than 50k characters. Clear all your script files and use only this code in 1 file.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide a reprex, mcve nor a mwe since the code imports a Gmail message in very specific HTML-markup that's going to be split by the script, resulting in (apparently) the number of characters in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit may be elsewhere in your code. Chances are that there is an attempt to put more than 50,000 characters in some cell.

Spreadsheet writes are lazy, and the error may only get shown when the script terminates, or at `flush()`, as the case seems to be here. To debug, add a `flush()` after every `Range.setValues()` and `Range.setValue()` call. Use `console.log()` to find what the values you are writing look like.

Comment: I was indeed overlooking an earlier attempt to monitor values by putting some part of the imported email into one cell. It was somewhere in line 10, while the apparantly provoking snippet was nearby line 70.